# JavaScript funciona no Desktop mas não funciona no Android

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma pagina em ASP.NET e nessa tela tem uma função JavaScript para permitir somente a digitação de números em alguns campos.

Quando rodo no Desktop (qualquer navegador) essa função funciona corretamente, mas quando abro essa pagina no navegador do Android a tela permite que se digite letras onde não poderia pois tem a função do JavaScript que deveria impedir isso.

Ou seja a função JS não funciona nos navegadores do Android (Navegador padrão e o Chrome). Obs: a função de JavaScript está ativa nos dois navegadores.

Segue uma parte do código da pagina..
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se precisar de mais informações eu providencio.....
Agradeço a ajuda.
Eduardo

Answer (score 1):

Fala Eduardo,

Seria bom você postar o código que ta usando no Java.

Mas provavelmente você está usando um webView, certo? Certifique-se que após a declaração da webView, você está colocando isso:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Abraços.

Comment: Ola Leonardo... o código do Java está na imagem anexa a minha pergunta. essa tela é uma pagina em ASP.NET no meu servidor que eu acesso através de um navegador como o Chrome por exemplo. o que seria um "webView" ...?

Comment: Eu achei que você estivesse incorporando essa página dentro da sua aplicação Android, pra isso você precisaria de um webView, onde você carregaria a página dentro. Nesse seu caso, é no próprio Chrome que habilita o JavaScript, vai no **Menu do Chrome > Configurações > Configurações do Site > JavaScript (deve estar como permitido)**

Comment: Eu já tinha verificado essa permissão e ela esta como "Permitir JavaScript"...